# Install SSL Certificates on Docker Image

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

- I am using EC2 instance to host my PHP app (Codeigniter) which is
  using Amazon Linux AMI ( Not Debian).
- Now I have created docker containers for the app which is using
  the base image - php:5.6-apache (Debian)

I am struggling with the installation of the SSL certificates in the docker container which was previously installed on the host machine.

As host and container have different Linux distribution. How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you already able install on the host machine, Then I will recommend port HTTP port of docker with host HTPPS port.

Comment: I have tried it. I am getting the error - ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on the browser.